# Flask: Update Code Reference for: current_app._get_current_object()

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning Python and Flask together.  I'm updating a code example to the latest Flask version (2.2.2) and PyCharm is reporting the following warning:

`Access to a protected member _get_current_object of a class`

in reference to the first line of the send_mail method

`app = current_app._get_current_object()`

What is a more appropriate way to code the statement?

```py
from threading import Thread
from flask import current_app, render_template
from flask_mail import Message
from . import mail

def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)
def send_email(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    msg = Message(app.config['FLASKY_MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX'] + ' ' + subject,
                  sender=app.config['FLASKY_MAIL_SENDER'], recipients=[to])
    msg.body = render_template(template + '.txt', **kwargs)
    msg.html = render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)
    thr = Thread(target=send_async_email, args=[app, msg])
    thr.start()
    return thr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current_app is a [proxy to your Flask app instance](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/appcontext/#purpose-of-the-context). It has your application's context. You don't need to access protected members from current_app class. Simply import it as app or alias it as app later on and perform your operations. For example:

```
# Importing and aliasing current_app
from flask import current_app as app

# this is perfectly fine
sender = app.config['FLASKY_MAIL_SENDER']
```

You shouldn't access protected members from a library or a framework. Only use members exposed by public API, or risk breaking your code in a future library update.

Comment: I know this is old, and this looks like a code snippet from the Flask Megatutorial series. When the author introduced Blueprints, I noticed the addition of `._get_current_object` into `current_app`. What could be the reason? Shouldn't `current_app` work by itself?

Comment: @JeffP hello. I have not used Flask for quite some time.  As a result I am not in a position to address your query. Perhaps, ask it as a separate question instead?